# How should I sanitize Laravel query if using whereRaw()?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.1 and the Eloquent ORM in a project. I need to query the database to find people using their name or part of the name.

If a person is named John Doelington, I want all the search terms `john`, `doelin`, `john doe` to find that John Doelington. However, the first name and last name are stored in different columns. Currently I am using this query:

```
$people = Person::whereRaw(
                     'CONCAT(first_name, \' \', last_name) 
                      LIKE \'%'.$search.'%\'')
                 ->get();
```

Looking at the logs I see a lot of errors - every time there is a `'` symbol it breaks the query. It seems that I am outside the safe zone with the `whereRaw()` function and someone could pass god knows what to SQL.

What should I do here?

Should I sanitize the input manually? If so, what should I do? Remove the `'` and what else? And what if query actually has to contain the `'` symbol?

Maybe there is a safer way to perform this query? Can I use Eloquent but pass parameters to query in the PDO style when using `whereRaw()`?

If it makes difference, I am using MySQL for the database.

I am aware that I could make a concatenated column for the full name, however I am looking for an Eloquent solution first before using this fallback.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L652), it's clear that `whereRaw`'s second argument accepts array bindings, so you can write your query as:

```
$search = "%{$search}%";
$people = Person::whereRaw("(CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) like ?)", [$search])
                 ->get();
```

You can also try the [Full-Text search](http://creative-punch.net/2013/12/implementing-laravel-4-full-text-search/).